# VBA - ComboBox with values inside a named range

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to load some values in a combobox using a combination of a named range and another combobox :

```
CBOX_NOMENCLAT.value = "SOCIAL"
```

When the value of this first combobox changes, it loads the second where I have my problem :

```
Private Sub CBOX_NOMENCLAT_Change()
    With CBOX_MOTIF
        .RowSource = Range(CBOX_NOMENCLAT)
    End With
End Sub
```

I indeed have a named range called `"SOCIAL"` returning 3 values. I would like them to be loaded in my `CBOX_MOTIF` (see below "MOTIF OD").

[image: My 2 combo boxes]

I thought about using the `INDIRECT` function but I couldn't find a way to make it work.

Could you please help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following.

```
Private Sub CBOX_NOMENCLAT_Change()
    With CBOX_MOTIF
        .RowSource = CBOX_NOMENCLAT.Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: could you explain me how to remove values from this combobox, please? "CBOX_MOTIF.Clear" does not seem to work. Should I use " RowSource = "" " ? Thx

EDIT : Used "CBOX_MOTIF.RowSource = VbNullString"

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`.RowSource = Range("MyWorkbook.xls!MySheet!" & CBOX_NOMENCLAT.Value)`

According to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/refer-to-named-ranges), the syntax for referencing a named range is:

[Workbook Name]![Sheet Name]![Named Range]

To evaluate the first combobox value and insert into the named range portion, you can pull the object reference out of the quotations and use an ampersand to concatenate.

This will only work if all of the needed named ranges exist on the same worksheet. Otherwise you will need to also set the sheet names dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for your input Moondogs, I used  @Dy.Lee's solution which works well.